# Recovering data from old RAID 1 NAS drive

Tags: lvm, data-recovery, mdadm, raid1

I'm trying to recover data from an old NAS drive that failed. I'm not sure of the cause of failure, but the files are relatively intact on the drive, and I've been able to pull some stuff off in the past using some really clunky debugfs methods. I'm coming at this again looking to actually get this thing mounted the correct and proper way to make my life easier. I'm running into some issues getting it to actually mount like a real and proper drive. The drive in question is SDB, and the partition SDB8 has all of my data on it.

```
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1     0B  0 disk  
sdb           8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1        8:17   0  19.1M  0 part  
├─sdb2        8:18   0    18M  0 part  
├─sdb3        8:19   0   954M  0 part  
├─sdb4        8:20   0   953M  0 part  
├─sdb5        8:21   0   191M  0 part  
├─sdb6        8:22   0   954M  0 part  
├─sdb7        8:23   0   976M  0 part  
└─sdb8        8:24   0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─md127     9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid1 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p4 259:1    0 381.5G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5 259:2    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p6 259:3    0  31.3G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p7 259:4    0   250G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p8 259:5    0   1.2T  0 part  /home
```

mdadm has this assembled into md127. It is a Raid1 array of 1(one) drive. And yes, I know that's ridiculous, but this is how the prebuilt NAS had it assembled.

```
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# mdadm -Dv /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jul 13 20:02:09 2013
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1949349781 (1859.04 GiB 1996.13 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1949349781 (1859.04 GiB 1996.13 GB)
      Raid Devices : 1
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Apr 30 14:35:46 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : BA-001075392B1C:1
              UUID : fca7e030:4cde51c2:8d9cd534:be1158a5
            Events : 96133

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       24        0      active sync   /dev/sdb8
```

When I go to mount this raid drive, I get the following output.

```
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# mount /dev/md127 /mnt/sdb8
mount: /mnt/sdb8: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

And here are my LV groups:

```
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# vgscan
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# lvscan
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# lvdisplay
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# vgdisplay
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]#
```

I've been stumbling around with LV stuff for the past couple of days, but I am being pretty cautious about preventing my drive from being wiped as part of an LV action of some kind. I'd really love to just get into this drive and pull the files out, and wipe it completely. Any thoughts about how to proceed from this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: lvm metadata is a readable string, so if `strings -w /dev/disk | grep 'Generated by LVM2'` lists lvm metadatas and dates, you could check what it has for the latest few timestamps (physical volumes, logical volumes, extents, etc.). if the volumes are not fragmented you could just access them by their offsets (`mount -o loop,ro,offset=x`) [if you only expect a single LV you could try this blindly for 1MiB offset]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "read-only copy" of the LVM block device for testing without fear:

```
dmsetup create lvm_pv_ro --readonly --table "0 "$(blockdev --getsz /dev/md127)" linear /dev/md127 0"
```

And then:

```
pvscan --cache /dev/mapper/lvm_pv_ro
pvs
vgs
```

## Update 1

I just realize that the creation of a "block device copy" makes LVM see the same PVs twice, which causes severe problems (similar problems would occur with a btrfs volume being mirrored). It may be possible to handle this but it should be much easier to use the original block device and just activate the LVs read-only:

```
pvscan --cache /dev/md127
vgchange -ay --readonly vg_name
# mount LVs
mount /dev/vg_name/lv_name /path/to/mountpoint
```

Of course, you can mount a filesystem read-only, too. Strangely, this does not prevent all write accesses (handling non-committed journal entries is the exception).

Comment: so now that I have a read only copy, how do I go about getting that mounted?

Comment: @grenademoose See my edit of my answer.

Comment: [dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# pvscan --cache /dev/md127
  pvscan[35852] PV /dev/md127 not used.
[dan-mech15g2rx sdb8]# pvscan --cache /dev/mapper/lvm_pv_ro 
  pvscan[35856] PV /dev/mapper/lvm_pv_ro not used.

Comment: @grenademoose Interesting. So what do you think/remember how `/dev/md127` was used? Do you still have access to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: there's two fstabs stored in misc partitions on that drive. Both are identical. 
`# stock fstab - you probably want to override this with a machine specific one
rootfs   /   auto  defaults 1  1
proc   /proc proc defaults 0  0
devpts /dev/pts  devpts mode=0620,gid=5  0  0
tmpfs  /var/volatile  tmpfs  defaults  0  0
tmpfs  /dev/shm  tmpfs mode=0777  0  0
tmpfs  /media/ram  tmpfs defaults  0  0
/dev/sda6  swap  swap  defaults 0  0
usbfs  /proc/bus/usb  usbfs defaults 0  0`